# Accessing array used in input name for data retention (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I'm rewriting a form that was using variables with numbers instead of an array for the names and ids in the input elements. (e.g. agency1, agency2, agency3...)

I know I can do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $AMOUNT_OF_AGENCIES; $i++)
{
  <label for="agency<?= $i; ?>">Agency Name</label><input type="text" name="agency[]" id="agency<?= $i; ?>">
}
```

to output the input elements that I need and within an easier-to-use array, but I would also like to have data retention in case the form errors out because of a validation error in another part of the form.

Can I do this?

```
<input type="text" name="agency[]" id="agency<?= $i; ?>" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_POST['agency[$i]']); ?>">
```

Comment: That's almost correct : you have to use `$_POST['agency'][$i]` instead of `$_POST['agency[$i]']`

Comment: @roberto06 that makes sense, thanks! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Done. And please try and refrain from using short tags such as `<?= $var; ?>`, `<?php echo $var; ?>` is much better and compatible with **ALL** PHP versions.

Comment: Fair enough.  The form I'm rewriting is in classic ASP, and after so many `<%= %>` I get envious... normally I use `<?php //code ?>` but I was getting lazy.

Comment: @roberto06 I'm sorry but I need to express that I disagree with your advice on the short tags. They are pretty much a standard these days, and after PHP 5.4 they are enable no matter what configuration you use. So if the server supports it and unless there is a concern that the code needs to work on pre-5.4, it is very safe to use. :-)

Comment: @sidyll You're right, in this case, the short tags obviously work, but, sadly, all web hosting companies and the servers they provide are still far from having PHP 5.4. I think it's always a better habit to use `<?php echo ?>`, just in case, but I guess I'm just a bit old school ;)

Comment: Fortunately, I'm working on a website that's hosted on-site. :) (I have direct control over what version of PHP is installed.)

But I will keep what you said in mind, cause I do some freelance work occasionally.

Comment: @roberto06 Yes, I agree. I think that we can say that if you're working on a specific project (like what appears to be yours, Tiffany) with a specific target server where capabilities are known, using short tags is a matter of preference and easiness of typing :D — however for projects that need a large deployment in unknown or uncertain environments the full written tag is definitely the safe way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's almost correct : You have to use

```
$_POST['agency'][$i]
```

instead of

```
$_POST['agency[$i]']
```